# ReactJS: How to make this image carousel run smoother?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, carousel

I'm trying to make an image carousel from Scratch in ReactJS.

This is what I have so far:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/optimistic-elbakyan-4vzer?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Drag with your mouse to change the image. Try it and you'll see that at some speeds it feels a little, stuttering? I don't really know how to explain it, and english isn't my first language.

Any suggestions to make it run smoother? I'm experimenting, so maybe my approach isn't the best. I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine on my end, the only thing is sometimes when dragging your mouse will still be dragging even when you aren't holding left click sometimes (probably when you mouse leaves the page then you let go)

Comment: I noticed that too, and I think it happens when you drag the actual picture. I just set the `user-select` to none and seems to be fixed. Code updated, but still having some stuttering when swiping not too fast, but not too slow neither.